# Update rows based on another single row selected without DECLAREing variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to update rows based upon another single row.

I want to update these:

```
SELECT field_one, field_two, field_three 
  FROM some_table WHERE user_ID = 296
```

With the values in this SELECT:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 * field_one, field_two, field_three 
    FROM some_table 
   WHERE user_ID = 500 
ORDER BY ID
```

Currently I am only updating field_one using:

```
DECLARE @field_one nvarchar(1000)

SELECT @field_one = field_one
  FROM some_table WHERE user_ID = @copy_user_ID

UPDATE some_table 
   set field_one = @field_one  
 where user_ID = @user_ID
```

Is there a way to do this with every field without having to DECLARE all of the variables?

Comment: For what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see, in FoxPro you could use SCATTER and GATHER :-)

But here, you can do this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Field_one = a.Field_one, 
    Field_two = a.Field_two, 
    Field_three = a.Field_three
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 1 field_one, field_two, field_three 
        FROM some_table WHERE user_ID = 500 
        ORDER BY ID) a
WHERE user_ID = 296
```

For an extra tip.  You can get a list of all the fields of a table, comma separated, in SSMS by opening up the Object Explorer pane showing the table, then click on the plus(+) sign to show the folders under the table.  Then just click on the Columns folder and drag it to your query pane.

Comment: Very nice, except you shouldn't have the * in the derived table.

Comment: Thanks G Mastros, didn't catch that.